AWS Amplify and Amazon Cognito: PostAuthentication Lambda Trigger on Re-login
I am using AWS Amplify and Amazon Cognito for user authentication in my Angular application. On the first login attempt, everything works fine. However, after logging out and attempting to log in again, I encounter the following error:
 UserLambdaValidationException: PostAuthentication failed with error 2024-09-02T02:32:11.601Z ae4ad2da-95ec-450f-9ca9-3a639373ae44 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds.
Additionally, I have set up a Lambda trigger for the PostAuthentication event to verify the user without requiring an OTP. The strange part is that sometimes, after waiting for 30 minutes to an hour, I can log in successfully again.
Steps to Reproduce:

Log in using AWS Amplify and Amazon Cognito.
Log out.
Attempt to log in again immediately.
Observe the error mentioned above.

Observations:

The error indicates a timeout in the PostAuthentication Lambda trigger.
The issue seems to resolve itself after waiting for a period (30 minutes to an hour).

Questions:

What could be causing the PostAuthentication Lambda trigger to time out on subsequent login attempts?
Why does the issue resolve itself after waiting for some time?

Authentication should work anytime.

Are you able to share the lambda function?
